# MLRun Docker failed, port is already allocated

Tags: docker, mlrun

I installed MLRun to the docker and I got

```
Error invoking remote method 'docker-start-container': Error: (HTTP code 500) server error - driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint desktopdockertools-mlrun-api-1 (a5a67db8a74bf4981d44477ffb77dccb25d2401d8fdd95c64262de30ed6d1a56): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated
```

Do you have any experience?

I installed different MLRun versions with Jupyter (usage compose.with-jupyter.yaml) and without Jupyter (compose.yaml), but I still see the same issue. I made installation based on https://docs.mlrun.org/en/latest/install/local-docker.html#install-local-docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened based on more MLRun installations, where first installation allocated requested port 8080 and other installations failed. The work-arround is:

- delete container from docker
- do new installation

If you need to use more MLRuns (e.g. with jupyter and without jupyter), you have to change ports in YAML files.

Answer (score 2):

This error is telling you, that you are running another service (application) on `localhost` (probably your computer) with port `8080`.

So basically you have two options on how to solve this problem:

1. run `MLRun` Docker instance on different port
2. find and stop the running application and then run the `MLRun` Docker instance

**Solution for case 1.:**

You have to change setting in Docker `compose.yaml.` file, like this:

```
services:
  mlrun-api:
    image: "mlrun/mlrun-api:${TAG:-1.0.6}"
    ports:
      - "8180:8080"
    environment:
      MLRUN_ARTIFACT_PATH: "${SHARED_DIR}/{{project}}"
      # using local storage, meaning files / artifacts are stored locally, so we want to allow access to them
      MLRUN_HTTPDB__REAL_PATH: /data
      MLRUN_HTTPDB__DATA_VOLUME: "${SHARED_DIR}"
      MLRUN_LOG_LEVEL: DEBUG
      MLRUN_NUCLIO_DASHBOARD_URL: http://nuclio:8070
      MLRUN_HTTPDB__DSN: "sqlite:////data/mlrun.db?check_same_thread=false"
      MLRUN_UI__URL: http://localhost:8060
      # not running on k8s meaning no need to store secrets
      MLRUN_SECRET_STORES__KUBERNETES__AUTO_ADD_PROJECT_SECRETS: "false"
      # let mlrun control nuclio resources
      MLRUN_HTTPDB__PROJECTS__FOLLOWERS: "nuclio"
    volumes:
      - "${SHARED_DIR:?err}:/data"
    networks:
      - mlrun

  mlrun-ui:
    image: "mlrun/mlrun-ui:${TAG:-1.0.6}"
    ports:
      - "8060:8090"
    environment:
      MLRUN_API_PROXY_URL: http://mlrun-api:8080
      MLRUN_NUCLIO_MODE: enable
      MLRUN_NUCLIO_API_URL: http://nuclio:8070
      MLRUN_NUCLIO_UI_URL: http://localhost:8070
    networks:
      - mlrun

  nuclio:
    image: "quay.io/nuclio/dashboard:${NUCLIO_TAG:-stable-amd64}"
    ports:
      - "8070:8070"
    environment:
      NUCLIO_DASHBOARD_EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESSES: "${HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - mlrun

networks:
  mlrun: {}
```

**Solution for case 2.:**

This case require some investigation, I recommend you to try to look for some other Docker containers with command `docker ps -a` where you can see other containers and their used ports. If you will find some containers using the same port `8080`, you should stop and delete them with command `docker stop <container_id / container_name>; docker rm <container_id / container_name>` and then run `MLRun` container

In case you don't see any other container running on port `8080`, you have to find the service (application) by using commands like:

```
# for unix like systems
# if you are using Windows, try to find the similar one command

netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':8080' 
lsof -i :8080
```

After you find the process of the service running on port `8080`, you can kill the process with command `kill <PROCESS_ID>` and then run `MLRun` container.